# Right side contour integral picture in TikZ

Tags: tikz-styles

How to draw the attached picture in Ti*k*Z environment?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far and where exactly is your problem with drawing this?

Comment: I have tried using the arc formula. I have tried searching for something similar on StackExchange but all I get is on the left side. As you can see the one I want is on the right side. I don't know how to flip it.

Comment: In this simple case `\tikz\draw(0,0)--(2,0)arc[start angle=150,end angle=-150,radius=2]--+(-2,0);` should draw something alike. Though, you need to explain what the subject of the question has to do with its body.

Comment: For the future: If you tried something, it is always better to show what you tried. This way, it is much easier to help you. =)

Answer (score 1):

Like this (the grid is only for reference points)?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,decoration={markings, 
            mark= between positions 0.2 and 0.8 step 30mm 
            with {\arrow{latex}}}
        ] 
        \draw[gray!20] (-5,-3) grid[step=.5] (3,3);
        \draw[postaction={decorate},line width=3pt] (-4.5,1)--(-1.73,1);
        \draw[postaction={decorate},line width=3pt] (-1.73,1) arc (150:-150:2);
        \draw[postaction={decorate},line width=3pt] (-1.73,-1)--(-4.5,-1);
        \draw[-latex] (-5,0)--(2.5,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5) node[above] () {$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you avoid drawing this in three different parts if you want your path to be smooth. See picture below:

[image: error in path]

Here's a way to do it in one line:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=2pt] ([xshift=-2cm]2:150) -- (2:150) arc[start angle=150, end angle=-150, radius=2] --++ (-2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: smooth path]